# Initialise a instance variable via a function

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers

I have a bunch of UILabels that need to be all setup the same but with different frames. As there is a lot of them I thought I would lower the amount of code by making a function to do it:

```
-(void)addField:(UILabel *)label withFrame:(CGRect)frame toView:(id)view {
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    [view addSubview:label];
}
```

and call it via:

```
[self addField:fieldOneLabel withFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 61, 53) toView:theView];
```

This works to a point that the fields show up correctly but looking into it fieldOneLabel isn't initialise so it's just a no longer referenced UILabel there. I thought I may have to use & but I guess my understanding isn't correct as it causes compiler errors. What should I be doing?

Comment: What compiler errors are you getting?

Comment: Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed it to not send the UILabel to to the function but return the label created:

```
-(UILabel *)addFieldWithFrame:(CGRect)frame toView:(id)view {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    [view addSubview:label];
    return label;
}
```

And called via:

```
fieldOneLabel = [self addFieldWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2 - 128, 13, 61, 53) toView:view];
```

Although similar to Scotts answer I wanted to avoid adding the view on another line.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to return the label and then add it to the UIView more like this:

```
-(UILabel*)createLabelWithText:(NSString*)text andFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [label setText:text];
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
    return label;
}
```

Then in your code you can do the following:

```
UILabel *xLabel = [self createLabelWithText:@"Some Text" andFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 61, 53)];
[theView addSubview:xLabel];
```

or if you want access to it later as a property:

```
self.xLabel = [self createLabelWithText:@"Some Text" andFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 61, 53)];
[theView addSubview:xLabel];
```

Comment: I would rename that method from addFieldWithFrame since it no longer adds the field to the view. A better solution would be to make a category for UILabel with the method +labelWithFrame:(CGRect)frame.

Comment: I'm happy to use that but is it possible to do it the way I'm currently doing it?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)addField:(UILabel * __autoreleasing *)fieldOneLabel withFrame:(CGRect)frame toView:(id)view {
    if (fieldOneLabel != nil) {
        *fieldOneLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        (*fieldOneLabel).layer.cornerRadius = 3;
        [view addSubview:(*fieldOneLabel)];
    }
}
```

and call it via:

```
[self addField:&fieldOneLabel withFrame:CGRectMake(20, 180, 61, 53) toView:theView];
```

use __autoreleasing can avoid arc memory issue

Comment: I had pretty close to this but it give the error Passing address of non-local object to __autoreleasing parameter for write-back. Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't possible in ARC anymore?

Comment: no build error or analysis error when building with xcode5 with arc enabled, so I think no arc issue

Comment: Thats what I'm on. Looking at the error people are saying it's because arc can't handle the memory management. I'll have to look into it further.

Comment: use __autoreleasing can avoid arc memory issue, see my updated codes

Comment: same issue, having it as a local var rather than an ivar fixes it (though it doesn't help my situation).